# What is a a sequence that has both convergent and divergent subsequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Is this possible? I thought it a sequence's subsequence can only either converge or diverge. Also doesn't it mean that if a sequence's subsequence converges, the original sequence converges as well and thus a diverging subsequence cannot exist.

Please help.

Comment: Yes, a convergent sequence cannot have a divergent subsequence. That just says that the example you want cannot  be a convergent sequence. "if a sequence's subsequence converges, the original sequence converges as well" yes or no, depending on what you mean. "a sequence's subsequence" is unclear, since a sequence has many subsequences. No: A divergent sequence can have _a_ convergent subsequence. Yes: If _every_ subsequence converges then the original sequence converges.

Answer (score 4):

Take $a_n=1$ for $n$ even and $a_n=n$ for $n$ odd.

$\{a_{2n}\}$ is a convergent subsequence and $\{a_{2n-1}\}$ is a divergent subsequence.